# Assign Tags using Powershell and reading from CSV

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a bit of a tricky one.

I have a csv file which has the following headers. I'm trying to assign the vmname in the csv the tags as mentioned in the csv under the relevant header (hope that makes sense).

vmname, resourcegroup, size, costcenter, displayname etc

When I run the first 20 lines it produces the azure text file as expected.

However if I run the second block lines 23 onwards to assign the tags to the vm it adds the key values but not the actual value and shows as blank in tags on the portal through the gui.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and wondered if anyone can see what I'm doing, the only thing I think it could be the $vm = $_.vmname, but can't see how.

The code I have is below

```
$csv = import-csv "C:\temp\book.csv"
$csv | foreach-object {
  $first =$_.VMName
  $Second =$_.ResourceGroup
  $size=$_.Size
  $t1= $_.Costcenter
  $t2= $_.Displayname
  $t3= $_.Environment
  $t4= $_.Project
  $t5= $_.Role
  $t6= $_.Template
  $t7= $_.DSC
  $t8= $_.Schedule
  $t9= $_.AppID
  $t10= $_.Service
  $t11= $_.REF
  $t12= $_.OS
  $t13= $_.Zone
  "The VM is $first, the RG is $second, the size is $size and tags $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4, $t5, $t6, $t7, $t8, $t9, $t10, $t11, $t12, $t13" | out-file C:\temp\Azure.txt -append
  }
##the above works fine

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"
$csv = import-csv "C:\temp\book.csv"
$vm = "$_.VMName"
$tags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"   -Name "$VM").Tags
$csv | ForEach-Object {
  $first =$_.VMName
  $t1= $_.Costcenter
  $t2= $_.Displayname
  $t3= $_.Environment
  $t4= $_.Project
  $t5= $_.Role
  $t6= $_.Template
  $t7= $_.DSC
  $t8= $_.Schedule
  $t9= $_.AppID
  $t10= $_.Service
  $t11= $_.REF
  $t12= $_.OS
  $t13= $_.Zone

$tags += @{
Costcenter="$t1"
Displayname="$t2"
Environment="$t3"
Project="$t4"
Role="$t5"
Template="$t6"
DSC="$t7"
Schedule="$t8"
AppID="$t9"
Service="$t10"
DREF="$t11"
OS="$t12"
Zone="$t13"
    }
}

Set-AzureRmResource  -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -Name "$VM" -Tag $tags -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -verbose
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `$vm = "$_.VMName"` how does this work outside of a loop? this won't even work inside the loop, btw...

Comment: Should that be after the foreach-object .. if I hardcore a vm name it still doesn't assign the variables .. can get it to read the vm name from the csv by placing it after the foreach..

Comment: well, i don't understand what you are trying to achieve with this script, but the `set-azurermresource` is being called once, first foreach does literally nothing

Comment: You need to move the `Set-AzureRmResource` call inside the last `Foreach-Object` and change `-Name "$VM"` to `$_.VMName`

Comment: What I am trying to do is .. we have a csv file with the tags for the machines which we are migrating to Azure. To assign the tags I though if I can go through foreach vm using the headers assign the relevant tag... so create a hash table and then assign them hence set-azurermresource should that be in the loop? Think I may be stretching myself a tad too far. As it iterates through should it assign them and then go through next one, if I hardcore a single server name it all works (using variables listed in a table not csv) sorry for the essay

Comment: Hey Norrin,  please post the header and two or three rows of your CSV, so I have an idea of what that looks like.  Make sure to *REDACT* company names and domain names (AND PASSWORDS).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're over-complicating this task a bit.

If I understand correctly, what you want to do (in pseudo-code) is:

```
foreach $VM in $CSVfile
    Retrieve existing tags for $VM
    Add csv values to existing tags
    Set new tag set on $VM in azure
```

This should be pretty straightforward:

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"
$csv = import-csv "C:\temp\book.csv"

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    # Retrieve existing tags
    $tags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Name $_.VMName).Tags
    # Add new value pairs from CSV
    $tags += @{
        Costcenter  = $_.Costcenter
        Displayname = $_.Displayname
        Environment = $_.Environment
        Project     = $_.Project
        Role        = $_.Project
        Template    = $_.Template
        DSC         = $_.DSC
        Schedule    = $_.Schedule
        AppID       = $_.AppID
        Service     = $_.Service
        DREF        = $_.REF
        OS          = $_.OS
        Zone        = $_.Zone
    }

    # Update resource with new tag set
    Set-AzureRmResource  -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -Name $_.VMName -Tag $tags -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -verbose
}
```

If any of the tag names from your CSV file already exist as tags on the resource, make sure you add them manually, one at a time:

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"
$csv = import-csv "C:\temp\book.csv"

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    # Retrieve existing tags
    $tags = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -Name $_.VMName).Tags

    # Define new value pairs from CSV
    $newTags = @{
        Costcenter  = $_.Costcenter
        Displayname = $_.Displayname
        Environment = $_.Environment
        Project     = $_.Project
        Role        = $_.Project
        Template    = $_.Template
        DSC         = $_.DSC
        Schedule    = $_.Schedule
        AppID       = $_.AppID
        Service     = $_.Service
        DREF        = $_.REF
        OS          = $_.OS
        Zone        = $_.Zone
    }

    # Add new tags to existing set (overwrite conflicting tag names)
    foreach($tagName in $newTags.Keys){
        $tags[$_] = $newTags[$_]
    }

    # Update resource with new tag set
    Set-AzureRmResource  -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -Name $_.VMName -Tag $tags -ResourceType "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" -verbose
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, the setting tags worked a treat, although the second part of changing existing tags came across with an error although it still helped me out a great deal .. thanks again :)